# Calling an Angular controller from the back end

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications, client-server

I have quite simple Angular web app which communicates with the back end via AJAX.
The main controller retrieves data from the server side. 
Here a sample of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/NEuJ6/28/ and the full functional example http://fiddle.jshell.net/NEuJ6/28/show/

It's quite obvious that visiting http://jsfiddle.net/NEuJ6/28/#/that will trigger the controller I have built:

```
app.controller('ActionController', function ($scope) {
    alert("Here is where the magic stands out");
});
```

On the back end I have some very basic PHP functions that insert, update and delete rows in a database.

So is there any way of triggering the `ActionController` from the the back end for all the active connections of the web app?

I have thought of using websockets but I think that's an overkill.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your options are websockets or server sent events.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be for the client to poll the server periodically to check if it needs to activate the controller.
You can write a service that does that and activate it in the module's `run` method.

The frequency of the polling should be low enough to not flood your server with constant requests but high enough to provide the required responsiveness.

If you can use an async server framework such as node.js then you can achieve higher responsiveness easily by queuing the requests on the server